# Screenshot without root

Tags: android, screenshot

Which class is responsible for creating screenshots? Is it possible to change it and include in own project to  take screenshots of `ANY` application? Has anyone tried to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to change it and include in own project to take screenshots of ANY application?

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Development tools and rooted device users can take arbitrary screenshots. Apps can take "screenshots" of their own content, but not that of other apps, to help prevent malware from stealing data from other apps.